# provide time period in ffmpeg drawtext filter

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to add text to video using ffmpeg and wants text to appear for a given period of time. I am trying to use DrawText filter but don't know how to provide time period for this filter. Can Anybody please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`drawtext` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) has [timeline editing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) support (see the output of `ffmpeg -filters`). This can evaluate an [expression](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) and allows you to provide the time(s) of when the filter should be enabled.

This example will enable the filter from 12 seconds to 3 minutes:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,12,3*60)':fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Test Text'" -acodec copy output.mp4
```

The audio was [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) in this example.

If you do not have timeline editing support then you will need to get a newer version. You can simply download a [Linux build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) or follow a step-by-step [guide to compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Also see the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide).

Comment: thanx LordNeckbear, I figured it out and was using gte(t,12)*lte(t,30). But thanx for introducing new function between.

Comment: if i am executing commaing getting enable not found error .please give me link for new ffmpeg.so file

Comment: @Sanket990 You have to show your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output.