# How to add watermark as gif and text on video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

i am trying to add gif and text on video using ffmpeg somewhat similar to tiktok.
want it to be like tiktok ie on top right gif and text and after sometime left bottom same gif and text on the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i logo.gif -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x=10:y=10:format=auto:enable='lte(t,5)':shortest=1[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-20:format=auto:enable='gte(t,5)':shortest=1,drawtext=text='@user1872811':fontsize=16:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=40:enable='lte(t,5)',drawtext=text='@user1872811':fontsize=16:fontcolor=white:x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10:enable='gte(t,5)',format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -map 0:a -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

You will need to adjust `x` and `y` positions for overlay and drawtext depending on the GIF width x height.

Adapted from:

- [Text on video ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624103/)
- [provide time period in ffmpeg drawtext filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21355582/)
- [How to position drawtext text](https://superuser.com/a/939386/)
- [How to add watermark with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/)

Also see:

- [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing)
- [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay)
- [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext)

Comment: thanks it works but video quality is very bad..any idea how to get same video quality?

Comment: where to add this option?
after which command basically?

Comment: can you please tell me how to make it top right and then bottom left?

Comment: @user1872811 See the links in the answer *How to position drawtext text* or *How to add watermark with ffmpeg?*

Answer (score 0):

**Top-Left To Bottom-Right loop:**

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
 "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,W-w-10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,H-h-10)'" \
 -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

**Top-Right To Bottom-Left loop:**

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex \
 "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),W-w-10,10)':y='if(lt(mod(t,10),5),10,H-h-10)'" \ 
 -codec:a copy out.mp4
```

Idea is very simple

- Take every 10sec duration, get remainder sec i.e. mod(t,10)
- if sec < 5,  set top position else bottom position

Please note I have excluded text i.e. username.

Answer (score -1):

ffmpeg -y -i out.mp4 -i 1080_Happy_Holidays_Red_Videvo.mov -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=iw/4:-1[pip];[1][pip]overlay=100:100[watermark];[watermark][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" output.mp4

You have more examples on my webste but it is forbiddien to give here an URL. Send me a private message

Comment: can you please explain your answer?

Comment: whats the website?